# Adding business logic in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

This has been asked in few times in this thread. But sometimes its hard to make it decouple. Let say Im dealing with session, cookie stuff how do I decouple or basically how do I move the existing code out from the JSP? UseBean will be a good alternative. But how to deal with business logic with lot of HTTPServletRequest and HTTPServerletResponse and its related objects used services?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing web-applications in Java has evolved quite a lot over the past 10 or so years. PHP-style JSP pages may have been ok-ish in 1999 but not today. At very minimum, you should isolate your business-logic in a servlet and only have your rendering/view in the JSP. That is just the bare-minimum to pass some form of basic level of hygiene. If you are doing any sort of new development or even refactoring, you should look into a more refined MVC/MVP framework. Spring is a good candidate. Maybe not the "coolest" but definitely established and well-known. The tutorial Andrea mentioned is a good place to start. And don't get too nervous about things like "how does it make sure the right request and session is used" - that is what spring-mvc does, it's the core functionality. Go through the tutorials, try it out and then dig deeper to understand what is happening under the hood and how you can customize the behavior to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a MVC patter to add the business logic to your web application on Java classes instead of add the logic into the JSP.

Take a look to that: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part3.html

Comment: Thanks. BTW this is a spring tutorial. With dependency injection and so on yo can simply access the HTTPServlet objects implicitly. However Im referring to basic servlet, JSPs.

Comment: With basic Servlet you could import your Jar file on Servlet so you could implement the Business logic on external java classes

Comment: So how do you make sure that you have the same request, response, session etc. are used in both the java class and the JSP you used?

Comment: If you call the jars from the servlet, you are under an http session. From the same servlet used to execute the business logic classes, you call a jsp with the results.